# Magento 2: Is it possible to create Product attributes sets and their options programmatically but not during the install

Tags: magento2, attributes, catalog

We are developing a REST API that extends magento 2's functionality. One thing we need this API to do is to create attributes "on the fly" based on the custom JSON product payload sent.

For example part of the product payload will contain:

```
options: [
   {
      code: "Country Made",
      value: "New Zealand",
   },
   {
      code: "Color",
      value: "Red"
   }
]
```

In this example, when creating the product, it will create a new attribute "Country Made" because it doesn't exist, and assign the existing attribute "Color" to the Color field.

Ive seen a lot of forum posts showing how to add attributes using the InstallData but none on how to add attributes by calling a function or model.

I've also seen a few on how to do it via the command line, we also can not do this

Im also asking for our magento developer - I roughly know how to read PHP and have a basic understanding of magento, so try to keep it simple so I can answer any questions you might have :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to add attribute options in the fly, you can use this class : `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\OptionManagement` for example and then refresh cache attribute with such as `$entityTypeModel->refreshCacheAttributes()`. In order to add an attribute, you can use `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute` but I never test it. It is just some code area to lookup, I let you create the code yourself by looking deeper in the Magento core code